# NameError: name 'jam' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence

I followed along a tutorial at https://towardsdatascience.com/audio-to-guitar-tab-with-deep-learning-d76e12717f81 but i am getting an error.

```
# Initialize variables
cnt_row = -1
cnt_col = 0
cnt_zero = 0

# Grab all relevant MIDI data (available in MIDI_dat)
for i in range(0, len(jam['annotations'])):
    if jam['annotations'][int(i)]['namespace'] == 'note_midi':
        for j in range(0, len(sorted(jam['annotations'][int(i)]['data']))):
            cnt_row = cnt_row + 1
            for k in range(0, len(sorted(jam['annotations'][int(i)]['data'])[int(j)]) - 1):
                if cnt_zero == 0:
                    MIDI_arr = np.zeros((len(sorted(jam['annotations'][int(i)]['data'])), len(sorted(jam['annotations'][int(i)]['data'])[int(j)]) - 1), dtype = np.float32)
                    cnt_zero = cnt_zero + 1
                if cnt_zero > 0:
                    MIDI_arr = np.vstack((MIDI_arr, np.zeros((len(sorted(jam['annotations'][int(i)]['data'])), len(sorted(jam['annotations'][int(i)]['data'])[int(j)]) - 1), dtype = np.float32)))
                    cnt_zero = cnt_zero + 1  # Keep
                if cnt_col > 2:
                    cnt_col = 0
                MIDI_arr[cnt_row, cnt_col] = sorted(jam['annotations'][int(i)]['data'])[int(j)][int(k)]
                cnt_col = cnt_col + 1
MIDI_dat = np.zeros((cnt_row + 1, cnt_col), dtype = np.float32)
cnt_col2 = 0
for n in range(0, cnt_row + 1):
    for m in range(0, cnt_col):
        if cnt_col2 > 2:
            cnt_col2 = 0
        MIDI_dat[n, cnt_col2] = MIDI_arr[n, cnt_col2]
        cnt_col2 = cnt_col2 + 1
        
 # Return the unique MIDI notes played (available in MIDI_val)
MIDI_dat_dur = np.copy(MIDI_dat)
for r in range(0, len(MIDI_dat[:, 0])):
    MIDI_dat_dur[r, 0] = MIDI_dat[r, 0] + MIDI_dat[r, 1]
tab_1, = np.where(np.logical_and(MIDI_dat[:, 0] >= start, MIDI_dat[:, 0] <= stop))
tab_2, = np.where(np.logical_and(MIDI_dat_dur[:, 0] >= start, MIDI_dat_dur[:, 0] <= stop))
tab_3, = np.where(np.logical_and(np.logical_and(MIDI_dat[:, 0] < start, MIDI_dat_dur[:, 0] > stop), MIDI_dat[:, 1] > int(stop-start)))
if tab_1.size != 0 and tab_2.size == 0 and tab_3.size == 0:
    tab_ind = tab_1
if tab_1.size == 0 and tab_2.size != 0 and tab_3.size == 0:
    tab_ind = tab_2
if tab_1.size == 0 and tab_2.size == 0 and tab_3.size != 0:
        tab_ind = tab_3
if tab_1.size != 0 and tab_2.size != 0 and tab_3.size == 0:
    tab_ind = np.concatenate([tab_1, tab_2])
if tab_1.size != 0 and tab_2.size == 0 and tab_3.size != 0:
    tab_ind = np.concatenate([tab_1, tab_3])
if tab_1.size == 0 and tab_2.size != 0 and tab_3.size != 0:
    tab_ind = np.concatenate([tab_2, tab_3])
if tab_1.size != 0 and tab_2.size != 0 and tab_3.size != 0:
    tab_ind = np.concatenate([tab_1, tab_2, tab_3])
if tab_1.size == 0 and tab_2.size == 0 and tab_3.size == 0:
    tab_ind = []
if len(tab_ind) != 0:
    MIDI_val = np.zeros((len(tab_ind), 1), dtype = np.float32)
    for z in range(0, len(tab_ind)):
        MIDI_val[z, 0] = int(round(MIDI_dat[tab_ind[z], 2]))
elif len(tab_ind) == 0:
    MIDI_val = []
MIDI_val = np.unique(MIDI_val)
if MIDI_val.size >= 6:
    MIDI_val = np.delete(MIDI_val, np.s_[6::])
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-070b180aefc0> in <module>
      5 
      6 # Grab all relevant MIDI data (available in MIDI_dat)
----> 7 for i in range(0, len(jam['annotations'])):
      8     if jam['annotations'][int(i)]['namespace'] == 'note_midi':
      9         for j in range(0, len(sorted(jam['annotations'][int(i)]['data']))):

NameError: name 'jam' is not defined
```

**Now i'm kinda new to coding, so i'm not quite sure what jam is referring to, but since i was following a tutorial, i really don't understand why it isn't defined? Thank you in advance for helping a beginner out.**

Comment: `jam` isn't defined, not much to say there. If this is exactly the tutorial code, then it has a bug.

Comment: @tdelaney is correct, it looks like ‘jam’ is meant to be some sort of data but I think the tutorial has a bug or simply gave you the wrong name for a variable.

Comment: Are you in an IDE or running from the console? After the error, you could look at the variables such as CQT to see if they are things that have an 'annotations' element. (from the command line its `python -i myscript.py`).

Comment: Well thats unfortunate. I understand if you don't have the time or don't want to, but the tutorial is at https://towardsdatascience.com/audio-to-guitar-tab-with-deep-learning-d76e12717f81 if that clears anything up. Thank you for your comments :) Edit: I use jupyter lab for running the code.

Answer (score 1):

you need to declare a variable jam and assign it a value from where ever you are getting it, python will not allow declaration in this manner.

```
cnt_row = -1
cnt_col = 0
cnt_zero = 0
jam = MIDI_dat <------- (or the variable from which you are accessing the data from)

# Grab all relevant MIDI data (available in MIDI_dat)
for i in range(0, len(jam['annotations'])):
    if jam['annotations'][int(i)]['namespace'] == 'note_midi':
        for j in range(0, len(sorted(jam['annotations'][int(i)]['data']))):
            cnt_row = cnt_row + 1
            for k in range(0, len(sorted(jam['annotations'][int(i)]['data'])[int(j)]) - 1):
                if cnt_zero == 0:
                    MIDI_arr = np.zeros((len(sorted(jam['annotations'][int(i)]['data'])), len(sorted(jam['annotations'][int(i)]['data'])[int(j)]) - 1), dtype = np.float32)
                    cnt_zero = cnt_zero + 1
                if cnt_zero > 0:
                    MIDI_arr = np.vstack((MIDI_arr, np.zeros((len(sorted(jam['annotations'][int(i)]['data'])), len(sorted(jam['annotations'][int(i)]['data'])[int(j)]) - 1), dtype = np.float32)))
                    cnt_zero = cnt_zero + 1  # Keep
                if cnt_col > 2:
                    cnt_col = 0
                MIDI_arr[cnt_row, cnt_col] = sorted(jam['annotations'][int(i)]['data'])[int(j)][int(k)]
                cnt_col = cnt_col + 1
```